# Android WebView not showing image Instagram embed

Tags: android, webview, android-webview, embed, instagram

I'm embed Instagram post to Android WebView, but the picture not show

Here is the screenshot
[Instagram picture not show](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3DAeo.png)

Here is my WebView code:

```
@SuppressLint("SetJavaScriptEnabled")
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    WebView webView = (WebView) findViewById(R.id.webview);
    webView.setHorizontalScrollBarEnabled(false);
    webView.setVerticalScrollBarEnabled(false);
    webView.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
    webView.getSettings().setUserAgentString(USER_AGENT);
    webView.loadDataWithBaseURL(null, TEXT_INSTAGRAM, "text/html", "utf-8", null);
}

private String TEXT_INSTAGRAM = "<blockquote class=\"instagram-media\" data-instgrm-captioned=\"\" data-instgrm-version=\"7\" style=\" background:#FFF; border:0; border-radius:3px; box-shadow:0 0 1px 0 rgba(0,0,0,0.5),0 1px 10px 0 rgba(0,0,0,0.15); margin: 1px; max-width:658px; padding:0; width:99.375%; width:-webkit-calc(100% - 2px); width:calc(100% - 2px);\"><div style=\"padding:8px;\"> <div style=\" background:#F8F8F8; line-height:0; margin-top:40px; padding:62.4537037037% 0; text-align:center; width:100%;\"> <div style=\" background:url(data:image/png;base64,iVBORw0KGgoAAAANSUhEUgAAACwAAAAsCAMAAAApWqozAAAABGdBTUEAALGPC/xhBQAAAAFzUkdCAK7OHOkAAAAMUExURczMzPf399fX1+bm5mzY9AMAAADiSURBVDjLvZXbEsMgCES5/P8/t9FuRVCRmU73JWlzosgSIIZURCjo/ad+EQJJB4Hv8BFt+IDpQoCx1wjOSBFhh2XssxEIYn3ulI/6MNReE07UIWJEv8UEOWDS88LY97kqyTliJKKtuYBbruAyVh5wOHiXmpi5we58Ek028czwyuQdLKPG1Bkb4NnM+VeAnfHqn1k4+GPT6uGQcvu2h2OVuIf/gWUFyy8OWEpdyZSa3aVCqpVoVvzZZ2VTnn2wU8qzVjDDetO90GSy9mVLqtgYSy231MxrY6I2gGqjrTY0L8fxCxfCBbhWrsYYAAAAAElFTkSuQmCC); display:block; height:44px; margin:0 auto -44px; position:relative; top:-22px; width:44px;\"></div></div> <p style=\" margin:8px 0 0 0; padding:0 4px;\"> <a href=\"https://www.instagram.com/p/BNYDM90gGJ3/\" style=\" color:#000; font-family:Arial,sans-serif; font-size:14px; font-style:normal; font-weight:normal; line-height:17px; text-decoration:none; word-wrap:break-word;\" target=\"_blank\">A view</a></p> <p style=\" color:#c9c8cd; font-family:Arial,sans-serif; font-size:14px; line-height:17px; margin-bottom:0; margin-top:8px; overflow:hidden; padding:8px 0 7px; text-align:center; text-overflow:ellipsis; white-space:nowrap;\">A photo posted by Sarah (@sarahsnyder) on <time datetime=\"2016-11-29T01:34:08+00:00\" style=\" font-family:Arial,sans-serif; font-size:14px; line-height:17px;\">Nov 28, 2016 at 5:34pm PST</time></p></div></blockquote><script async=\"\" defer=\"\" src=\"http://platform.instagram.com/en_US/embeds.js\"></script>";
```

How to fix this, so the embeded Instagram can show on WebView

Thanks

Comment: try to use `android:hardwareAccelerated="true"` in <application> tag of Manifest.

Comment: Hi @Ra thanks for your suggestion, I add android:hardwareAccelerated="true" on manifest but the picture still not show

Comment: use loadData instead of loadDataWithBaseUrl?

Comment: Sorry forgot that my code include this:
webView.getSettings().setUserAgentString(USER_AGENT);

If I remove this line, the Instagram picture show

Comment: But I need to set user-agent on my webView, any idea how to solve this ?

Comment: @EricWijaya hello dear,facing same problem .any solution?

Answer (score 4):

You need to change

```
<script async defer src="//platform.instagram.com/en_US/embeds.js">
```

to:

```
<script async defer src="https://platform.instagram.com/en_US/embeds.js">
```

in TEXT_INSTAGRAM.

Answer (score 3):

You have to change

```
webView.loadDataWithBaseURL(null, TEXT_INSTAGRAM, "text/html", "utf-8", null);
```

to

```
webView.loadDataWithBaseURL("https://www.instagram.com", TEXT_INSTAGRAM, "text/html", "utf-8", null);
```

Comment: My posts only show with a local url, not a https one, ive tried instagram url and it didnt work for me.

Answer (score 1):

You have defined your TEXT_INSTAGRAM  below the onCreate method.
Please change that by defining it inside Oncreate

```
@SuppressLint("SetJavaScriptEnabled")
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

private String TEXT_INSTAGRAM = "<blockquote class=\"instagram-media\" data-instgrm-captioned=\"\" data-instgrm-version=\"7\" style=\" background:#FFF; border:0; border-radius:3px; box-shadow:0 0 1px 0 rgba(0,0,0,0.5),0 1px 10px 0 rgba(0,0,0,0.15); margin: 1px; max-width:658px; padding:0; width:99.375%; width:-webkit-calc(100% - 2px); width:calc(100% - 2px);\"><div style=\"padding:8px;\"> <div style=\" background:#F8F8F8; line-height:0; margin-top:40px; padding:62.4537037037% 0; text-align:center; width:100%;\"> <div style=\" background:url(data:image/png;base64,iVBORw0KGgoAAAANSUhEUgAAACwAAAAsCAMAAAApWqozAAAABGdBTUEAALGPC/xhBQAAAAFzUkdCAK7OHOkAAAAMUExURczMzPf399fX1+bm5mzY9AMAAADiSURBVDjLvZXbEsMgCES5/P8/t9FuRVCRmU73JWlzosgSIIZURCjo/ad+EQJJB4Hv8BFt+IDpQoCx1wjOSBFhh2XssxEIYn3ulI/6MNReE07UIWJEv8UEOWDS88LY97kqyTliJKKtuYBbruAyVh5wOHiXmpi5we58Ek028czwyuQdLKPG1Bkb4NnM+VeAnfHqn1k4+GPT6uGQcvu2h2OVuIf/gWUFyy8OWEpdyZSa3aVCqpVoVvzZZ2VTnn2wU8qzVjDDetO90GSy9mVLqtgYSy231MxrY6I2gGqjrTY0L8fxCxfCBbhWrsYYAAAAAElFTkSuQmCC); display:block; height:44px; margin:0 auto -44px; position:relative; top:-22px; width:44px;\"></div></div> <p style=\" margin:8px 0 0 0; padding:0 4px;\"> <a href=\"https://www.instagram.com/p/BNYDM90gGJ3/\" style=\" color:#000; font-family:Arial,sans-serif; font-size:14px; font-style:normal; font-weight:normal; line-height:17px; text-decoration:none; word-wrap:break-word;\" target=\"_blank\">A view</a></p> <p style=\" color:#c9c8cd; font-family:Arial,sans-serif; font-size:14px; line-height:17px; margin-bottom:0; margin-top:8px; overflow:hidden; padding:8px 0 7px; text-align:center; text-overflow:ellipsis; white-space:nowrap;\">A photo posted by Sarah (@sarahsnyder) on <time datetime=\"2016-11-29T01:34:08+00:00\" style=\" font-family:Arial,sans-serif; font-size:14px; line-height:17px;\">Nov 28, 2016 at 5:34pm PST</time></p></div></blockquote><script async=\"\" defer=\"\" src=\"http://platform.instagram.com/en_US/embeds.js\"></script>";

WebView webView = (WebView) findViewById(R.id.webview);
webView.setHorizontalScrollBarEnabled(false);
webView.setVerticalScrollBarEnabled(false);
webView.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
webView.getSettings().setUserAgentString(USER_AGENT);
webView.loadDataWithBaseURL(null, TEXT_INSTAGRAM, "text/html", "utf-8", null);
}
```

Comment: Hi @Avinash Saran, I try your suggestion but picture still not show